# Neep help rewriting php query string to slashes in the URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

I would like to simplify the url on my website forum,
how can i rewrite this

```
forum.php?topic=10
```

to this

```
forum.php/topic/10
```

Comment: asked so many times...

Comment: disappointed... i was really hoping someone would give a funny answer using str_replace :)

Comment: Here it is: `str_replace(['?', '='], '/', 'forum.php?topic=10')` ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you mean `forum.php?topic=10` to `forum.php/topic/10`? I assume you mean the other way

What you need (untestet):

```
RewriteRule     ^/(.*).php/(.*)/([0-9]+)$        $1.php?$2=$3
```

But it would be better to make it this way:

```
RewriteRule     ^/(.*)/(.*)/([0-9]+)$        $1.php?$2=$3
```

Then your Url is only `forum/topic/10` without `.php`

Please take a further look into this:

http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: Thanks :), the addedbytes blog article really healped me out, as well as the code you provided :)